# I load my audio and when I want to load the filename I have some troubles

Tags: python, librosa

Import library

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
filename = get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096) 
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
print(len(y),sr)
```

With `get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096)` the function to get the path of the audio (.mp3) 36096

output

```
> NoBackendError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-12-e5b91455e58d> in <module>
>       1 filename = get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096)
> ----> 2 y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
>       3 print(len(y),sr)
>       4 each_file = filename.split('/')[-1]
>       5 genre_name = each_file.split('.')[0]
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
>     110 
>     111     y = []
> --> 112     with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
>     113         sr_native = input_file.samplerate
>     114         n_channels = input_file.channels
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py in audio_open(path, backends)
>     114 
>     115     # All backends failed!
> --> 116     raise NoBackendError()
> 
> NoBackendError:
```

any help please !

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870412/librosa-cant-open-wav-created-by-librosa

Answer (score 0):

You can load the audio file path directly into librosa and specify the given sample rate and whether it's mono or stereo. No need for the `get_audio_path` function.

```
import librosa
audio_path='C:/Users/audio/name.mp3'
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=44100, mono=False)
```

Documentation on `librosa.load` is here:
https://librosa.org/librosa/0.5.1/generated/librosa.core.load.html?highlight=load#librosa.core.load

If you need to get an audio file in a given path you can use `os`. This will get all the mp3 files in a given path:

```
import os

AUDIO_DIR = "C:/Users/my/audio/path"
all_mp3s_paths = [os.path.join(AUDIO_DIR, file) for file in os.listdir(AUDIO_DIR) if os.path.splitext(file)[-1] == ".mp3"]
```

Comment: The 2 methods together do not work, I have this error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\adil\\Desktop\\codes\\PROJ 1\\fma_small\\036\\036\\036096.mp3'

Comment: have you checked to see if that exact path exists?

Comment: Yes the path is correct.
RuntimeError: Error opening '/home/ub10/Desktop/PROJ 1/fma_small/036/036096.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.

Comment: O okay I would try updating librosa to the most recent version. Also are you able to load that file into a sound editor?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that I found:

1. You don't need to use the `get_audio_path` function.

   ```
   import librosa
   import librosa.display

   filename = 'C:/Users/audio/name.mp3' # make sure to add extension .wav or anything
   y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
   print(len(y), sr)
   ```
2. If the problem still occurs, recheck your audio data set path.